# Send email inviting existing participants to sign at any given time

Tags: docusignapi

I am generating an envelope with multiple signers.  When the envelope is created, all signers are set to in-person.  Later, the signers may change to email signers.

When the signers are changed to email signers, I would like to not email them.  I would instead prefer to email them at any time after they are changed to email signers (eg when an admin in my app presses an "email now" button).

Is this possible?  I have not been able to track down when and how emails are sent notifying email signers that a document is available for them to sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an Envelope using the DocuSign API, you specify whether each recipient is a "remote recipient" (i.e., will receive an email notification from DocuSign when it's their turn in the routing order), or an *in-person (aka "embedded") recipient* (i.e., will access the Envelope via a URL that you attain via a **POST Recipient View** API request).

- Once you make this determination during Envelope creation, simply
  changing a recipient from one type to another (i.e., from *remote
  recipient* to *in-person recipient* or vice versa) is not possible.
  You can still achieve the desired end result -- but to do so, you
  must actually delete the original recipient and add a new recipient
  in its place.
- If a recipient is designated as a *remote recipient*, DocuSign will automatically send them an email whenever it reaches their turn in the routing order -- it's not possible for you to change this behavior.

Given the scenario and objective you've described, you might consider implementing something like the following:

- When you create the Envelope via the API, specify a "placeholder" (fake) *embedded* recipient with routing order **1** and specify all other "real" recipients as *remote* recipients with routing order **2** or higher. It won't really matter what name/email you specify for the "placeholder" recipient (because you're subsequently going to delete this recipient altogether when it's time for others to begin signing) -- but do keep in mind that the recipient info will appear in the Envelope audit trail (History, etc.), so choose values that you won't mind seeing there.
- Then, when it's time for the *real* signing to happen (eg when an admin in your app presses an "email now" button), issue a **Delete Recipients** API request (`DELETE https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/ {envelopeId}/recipients`) to delete the "placeholder" recipient that you initially created as the first recipient (routing order = **1**).

Deleting the first recipient from the Envelope should make DocuSign advance the Envelope to the next recipient(s) in the routing order, at which point they'll automatically be sent the signing invitation email from DocuSign.

Comment: Is "routing order" the same thing as "signing order" in the UI? http://imgur.com/A0fe29C

Comment: Yes, same thing -- it's the sequence in which recipients will receive the Envelope. The corresponding REST API recipient property is "routingOrder".